# Avoid Publishing a page after an Edit

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, publishing-page

I have a publishing sub-site and created pages with my custom page layout. For each page after an edit user needs to publish it. Only then others can see change made. Is it possible to remove this extra effort and make only save page as final.

Note : Publishing feature is active

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Pages use SitePages. You just have edit page and stop edit page options on site pages, no need to publish these pages.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it is a publishing sub-site with only 
Pages. There is no SitePages